# Saving data between activities using external class

Tags: android, string, class, save, external

I'm developing an app that has to share strings between activities. I'm trying to get the seperate activities to call a public class with set and get methods. The calling the methods part works and I manage to get a response although the set value has to be rememberd by the set and get class. Here's a link to my set and get class, it's pretty basic: http://pastebin.com/0WabNKz3

Now my question is this: How do I make the set and get class to remember my values between sessions? Feel free ask questions if there's anything you didn't understand.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating invisible EditTextPreference that now hold the data that I want to keep because they can be shared easily.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `SharedPreferences`. That's the way to save data even after the app is closed and you can access it from anywhere:

```
public void savePrefrences(String key, String value)
    {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName(), 0);
        prefs.edit().putString(key, value).commit();
    }

    public String getPrefrences(String key)
    {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName(), 0);
        return prefs.getString(key, "");
    }
```

Save the prefrence when and whereever you want and get it whenever and from wherver you want.

The value will not delete when you close the app.

Comment: What should I replace SynergyApplication._context.getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName(), 0); with, Eclipse is saying SynergyApplication cannot be resolved as a variable. "context" is wrong too of course, what should it be instead?

Comment: You can just delete everything before "getSharedPreferences" if you are using it inside your activity.

Comment: @Luis what do you mean by "using it inside your activity"? It crashes when using it in my class when I'm extending activity

Comment: if you would need to use it in another class that is not extending activity, getSharedPreferences() would not be available, unless you provide the activity context to that class. However you error is not due to that. You need to post your log stacktrace to see what is the problem.

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited the answer. You just need a Context. If you;re inside an Activity then you can use this, if not, you should pass a Context to the funtion

Answer (score 0):

When you say saving between sessions, do you mean between the app being paused, or closed completely?

A good resource for lifecycle and storing data across sessions is:
//developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: By between sessions I mean that the data reamin between app restarts. Sharedpreferences would be ideal although I tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: I got a syntax error when not extending activity and when I did extend activity the app crashed on the line that got the syntax error earlier on. The line was the one where I tried to get the shared preferences.

Comment: Ok. Is there any chance you could post your SharedPreferences code?